# function is undefined error in angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm running into a problem trying to setup a fairly simple call using a factory and controller in angularjs. I've been attempting to follow the style guides of John Papa and Todd Motto in setting this up.

First I'm using 2 modules

```
(function(){

 'use strict';

  angular.module('app',[

  'app.core',
  'app.property'

     ]);
})();
```

In 'app.core' I define the factory

```
(function(){

'use strict';

angular.module('app.core')
  .factory('dataservice',dataservice);

dataservice.$inject = ['$http','$q'];

function dataservice($http,$q) {

 var service = {
    getListing: getListing
 };

 return service;


 function getListing() {

      var def = $q.defer;

      $http.get("http://acme.com/property/1?format=json")
        .success(function(data){
          service.getListing = data;
          def.resolve(data);
        });

      return def.promise;


 }
}
})();
```

and in 'app.property' I defined the controller

```
 (function(){

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app.property')
    .controller('PropertyCtrl',PropertyCtrl);

  PropertyCtrl.$inject = ['dataservice'];

  function PropertyCtrl(dataservice) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.listings = [];

  activate();

  function activate() {
    return getListing().then(function(){});
  }
  function getListing(){
    return dataservice.getListing().then(function(data){
      vm.listings = data;
      console.log("data is");
      console.log(data);
      return vm.listings;
    });
  }
  }
})();
```

the error I get in the console output is

Error: dataservice.getListing(...) is undefined except when I inspect dataservice in chrome I can see[image]

Further on I receive

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

TypeError: def.resolve is not a function
```

Despite these errors the remote call returns json fine.

Hoping someone with angular chops has an idea on where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. It should be `$q.defer()` but you've `$q.defer`

```
 function getListing() {
      var def = $q.defer();
      $http.get("http://acme.com/property/1?format=json")
        .success(function(data){
          service.getListing = data;
          def.resolve(data);
        });
      return def.promise;   
 }
```

Comment: Down voters do comment the reason also so that I can improve.

Comment: i didn't down-vote it, but I don't think this was the OP problem.  It may be *A* problem with his code, but I don't think it was the cause of the error he mentioned.

Comment: If you could see the error OP is getting, `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` which is related to defer. But in dataservice getlisting() is available. So it's clear that it's because of that

Comment: Yep your right!  +up-vote
I stopped after the first error was resolved.
I updated my plunker also to reflect your correction as well.
He was having multiple issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually create the modules you are building on:

Put this above your `app.property` module's objects:
`angular.module('app.property', []);`

Put this above your `app.core` module's objects:
`angular.module('app.core', []);`

You are basically attaching a factory and a controller to modules that don't exist.  You are trying to inject modules that don't exist into your primary module.

Here is a **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H2Xl7cxdcrJRxExgQuHN?p=preview)** showing the issues you were having resolved.  Your code has some other issues, but at least it's finding the modules now, which was your original problem.

It should also be noted that mohamedrias is also correct - you had an error in syntax by not putting `()` on your defer call.
I updated my plunker to include his correction as well.